# execute self unmarshal method or default unmarshal method base on condition in golang

Tags: json, go

I am a novice in golang. I have a struct **Item** .

```
type Item Struct{
   ...
}
```

and I know it has a default **UnmarshalJSON** method.
Now I want to unmarshal data to it.

For the data may has **two different** format. So my expection as below:

```
if condition {
    //execute default UnmarshalJSON
    json.Unmarshal(data, &item) 
}else{
    //execute my own UnmarshalJSON
    json.Unmarshal(data, &item) 
}
```

this is my own UnmarshalJSON.

```
func (item *Item) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error{
   ...
}
```

Maybe myself UnmarshalJSON will override default, so the two method could not be present at the same time. I want to know how to solve this kind problem which Unmarshal two different format data into one struct.

Comment: The solution is to use interface and then fetch the value from there. What you are asking is not possible in golang.

Comment: Nothing has a default UnmarshalJSON method. Please provide a real example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an interface whatever be the format you are getting from the json response and unmarshal the response into interface as:

```
func main(){
    var result interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonbytes, &result); err != nil{
         fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Then use type assertion to fetch the value underlying the interface. But I think in your case if you do not the underlying type of a key. Better is to use recursion to fetch the value.

```
func fetchValue(value interface{}) {
    switch value.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%v is an interface \n ", value)
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("%v is bool \n ", value)
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("%v is float64 \n ", value)
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a slice of interface \n ", value)
        for _, v := range value.([]interface{}) { // use type assertion to loop over []interface{}
            fetchValue(v)
        }
    case map[string]interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a map \n ", value)
        for _, v := range value.(map[string]interface{}) { // use type assertion to loop over map[string]interface{}
            fetchValue(v)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%v is unknown \n ", value)
    }
}
```

Working Code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-eZW1L89Lbu)

Above code will let you to fetch any type of value that is parsed into an interface.

**Note:**

> In golang it is defined that when you unmarshal unknown json into an
>   interface. It will be converted into following types:

```
bool, for JSON booleans
float64, for JSON numbers
string, for JSON strings
[]interface{}, for JSON arrays // slice of interface{}
map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
nil for JSON null
```